# iOS Swift Memory Bug, Doesn't Happen on Simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, memory, simulator

I have a bit of a confusing problem with memory in my iOS app. 
I am using the following function to download about 60 images:

```
func getDataFromUrl(url:NSURL, completion: ((data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError? ) -> Void)) {
    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) {  (data, response, error) in //Should already be async
        completion(data: data, response: response, error: error)
        }.resume()
}
```

As far as I can tell this is the recommended way of achieving this because it is asynchronous and downloads them one at a time. Unfortunately, somewhere memory isn't being deallocated correctly because I can see my memory continuing to increase and not dropping. The confusing part however is that in the simulator the memory stays relatively flat, as it should. On an iPhone 6, the memory linearly increases and crashes after about 5 minutes. On an iPhone 5s, it increases in a pattern that looks more exponential, and then rapidly drops upon receiving a memory warning, and never crashes.

Here is my code for context:

```
func cacheImage(teamNum : Int, url : String?) {
    if let urlString = url {
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
        getDataFromUrl(url!) { [unowned self] (data, response, error)  in
            guard let data = data where error == nil else { return }
            if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                self.imageCache.set(value: image, key: "\(teamNum)")
            } else {
                print(url)
            }
        }
    }
}

func fetchImageForTeam(teamNumber : Int, fetchedCallback : (UIImage)->(), couldNotFetch: ()->()) { // Is already async
    self.imageCache.fetch(key: "\(teamNumber)").onSuccess { (image) -> () in
        fetchedCallback(image)
        }.onFailure { (E) -> () in
            couldNotFetch()
    }
}
func getDataFromUrl(url:NSURL, completion: ((data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError? ) -> Void)) {
    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) {  (data, response, error) in //Should already be async
        completion(data: data, response: response, error: error)
        }.resume()
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*EDIT*

I am aware that downloading 60 images is generally a bad idea, and that I should be more "lazy" with my downloading, such that I get the image only just before I need it. For my particular purpose however, the device needs to show the images without significant internet connection, which means it must download them before hand.

The imageCache is Haneke disk Cache https://github.com/Haneke/Haneke

I am additionally aware that I can't hold that many images in memory, and that I should cache them to disk as I download them. This is what I am doing using the disk cache. It should not hold the images in memory, but simply write to disk, and read from disk, when I ask it to. Or do I have a really big understanding gap here?

Will `[unowned self]` correctly avoid a reference cycle as I thought it would? Or am I misunderstanding the function of the capture list and `unowned` keyword?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Just a couple of comments: (1) "asynchronous" has nothing to do with memory usage (2) "asynchronous" has to do with threads but you are not being careful about what thread you are actually on

Comment: Thanks Matt, but I'm perfectly aware of what asynchronous means. If I am reading the docs correctly the shared session should handle the data task asynchronously in order to avoid messing up the UI etc.

Answer (score 2):

This really has nothing to do with the asynchronous nature of the downloading. You should indeed download asynchronously, but you may be having some threading issues because of the way you are doing that.

You are building up memory because of this line:

```
self.imageCache.set(value: image, key: "\(teamNum)")
```

So you are storing *images* in *memory*. As long as `self` persists, all those images will persist in *memory*. You are trying to hold 60 images in memory simultaneously. You should certainly expect to crash if you do that. Images are *big*. You should *never* do that sort of thing; your app doesn't have the memory for it.

Now, you have not explained what `self.imageCache` actually *is*. But that is the heart of the matter. The fact that you get a warning and then a decrease in memory usage on one machine suggests that it is in fact a true cache, so all the images are being lost — they are flushed out of memory. The fact that that *doesn't* happen on a different machine may be because of the threading issue I referred to earlier (I don't know, because I don't know the details of what `self.imageCache` is, because you have concealed them).

But basically I would suggest that your strategy here is just wrong from the get-go. Don't even *try* to hold 60 images in memory, cached or not. Write them to disk as they are downloaded! This should be a download task, not a data task. Memory should hold only *references* to the images, not the image data itself.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick and thorough response!

Answer (score 1):

As matt correctly concluded, the increase in memory is likely due to the cache holding images in memory. Haneke uses `NSCache` for the "first level". `NSCache` has properties where you can control the maximum capacity of the memory used. You may figure out if you can set this somewhere in Haneke.

In addition to this, you should also control how many network requests are currently active at a time. If you just do this:

```
let urls = []("images/1", "images/2", ...)  // quite a lot urls
urls.forEach { self.cacheImage(123, url: $0) }
```

you actually start N network requests in parallel. However, the system will limit the maximum number of concurrent requests - which is four on iOS - **and especially in your case, this is a good thing**. Otherwise, the kernel will be forced to hold N buffers, each with the size of the image. All images would be loaded in parallel and finish roughly at the same time. You can imagine that the system would explode after a certain number of large images ;)

So, due to the limit of maximum requests to *one and the same host*, while four requests do actually progress, the others still pending will wait ready in the queue - and their timers for timeouts will count down.
The last url enqueued will have to wait the longest until it will be processed. This may cause issues with the timeouts.

Besides this, it seems suboptimal to download *large data* in parallel. So, I would experiment with restricting the maximum number of requests to less than 4, say one or two. Additionally, use a *separate* queue where you control the start of the network request: the NSURLSession task should only be created once this URL is actual ready to be downloaded.

A simple implementation to fetch a list of URLs *sequentially* is this:

```
func fetch(url: NSURL, completion: (ErrorType?)->()) {
   ...
}

func fetchSequentially(list: [NSURL], completion: (ErrorType?)->()) {
    func next<Generator: GeneratorType where Generator.Element == NSURL>(inout gen: Generator) {
        if let url = gen.next() {
            fetch(url) { error in
                //if error != nil { /* handle error */ }
                next(&gen)
            }
        } else {
            return completion(nil)
        }
    }
    var gen = list.generate()
    next(&gen)
}
```

A further improvement would be to load the images in chunks (implementing the NSURLSession delegates) and save them into a file, or creating N resumable background tasks, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the input. Your question about the maximum capacity of the cache was one of the first things I double checked after being stumped by this problem. It seems that Haneke does not limit the cache unless you set a Limit explicitly.

Comment: The problems you point out with timeouts, sequential downloads, etc all seem like very good considerations and potential problems but none of them strike me as able to cause the behavior I am seeing (the incrementally larger mem use). I do like your sequential download function though, it's pretty nifty :P and very Swifty.